# Setting <td> width using styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, styled-components

I have a table using styled components like this

```
return(
  <Table id="leaderboard_view" >
  <TableHead >LEADERBOARD</TableHead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <TableDataGrey>#</TableDataGrey>
        <TableData>PLAYER</TableData>
        <TableData>AWARD</TableData>
        <TableData>SCORE</TableData>
      </tr >
      { list.map(user => 
        <tr>
          <TableDataGrey>{user.place}</TableDataGrey>
          <TableData>{user.player}</TableData>
          <TableData>{user.award}</TableData>
          <TableData>{user.score}</TableData>
        </tr >
       )}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
 )
```

And it all renders and works but I have a problem that the first column is a lot bigger then the other ones. What I want to achieve is that the first column to be smaller like 15 % and the rest like 25% of the width. I have tried that in a couple of ways like using a styled col component like

```
    const SmallCol = styled.col`
 width: 15%;
`
const LargeCol = styled.col`
 width: 25%;
`
```

and then putting 1 small and 3 large of those styled components between the Table and TableHead but it makes no difference and I have tried to just use regular col without styled components but my styled `<tr>` doesn't seem to pick it up! Anyone who has done it or have a clue on how it can be done?

Here is also the style on my table components:

```
    const Table = styled.table`
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
`;

const TableHead = styled.thead`
font-size: 4vh;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
padding 2;
}
`;

const TableData = styled.td`
font-size: 3vh;
border: 1px solid LightGrey;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

`;

const TableDataGrey = styled.td`
font-size: 3vh;
color: LightGrey;
border: 1px solid LightGrey;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Try putting `table-layout: fixed` on the table.

Comment: @Jackson that did it! thank you! :)